# SQL Server Full Outer Join Returning Rows with all NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

When joining two tables using Full Outer Join, I am receiving results with NULL values in every column. The row count is the same as the count of the larger table. I would expect that at least one table columns would have values.
Here is my simple select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM InputXML X 
FULL OUTER JOIN ACM ON X.[file_name] = ACM.AllCharts
```

Comment: Do you have row(s) in your tables that have nothing but NULL values?

Answer (score 0):

It is a full join it is going to return null in left or right but if is returning a row full of nulls you will have to check if you have X.[file_name] or ACM.AllCharts with Null values, because when you compare null = null it gives you no results because null is not a value, it is something like unknown or infinite in math.